# Remove specific item from array by using value

Tags: react-native

Here's my code. 
I want remove an item from below by using their value or id. How can I do that. Is there a way to do it without filtering the array.

```
const names = [{name: 'Person1', id: 1}, {name: 'Person2', id: 2}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const names = [{name: 'Person1', id: 1}, {name: 'Person2', id: 2}]
names.splice(id, 1);
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

What's up?

So, you can do that with an array filter:

```js
   names.filter(person => person.id !== id)
```

Comment: Sorry, I made a Mistake

Answer (score 0):

You can use your own logic like:

```js
const names = [{name: 'Person1', id: 1}, {name: 'Person2', id: 2}]   
let filteredNames = []
for(i =0; i< names.length; i++)
{
  if(names[i].id != 2)
  {
     filteredNames.push(names[i])
  }
}
console.log(filteredNames);
```

If you want to use filter then:

```js
const names = [{name: 'Person1', id: 1}, {name: 'Person2', id: 2}]  

filteredName = names.filter((name) => {
  return name.id != 1;
})

console.log(filteredName)
```